# TFS 2010 installation on 2003 with SharePoint 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, tfs-2010

Is it possible to install Team Foundation Server 2010 on 2003 windows server with SharePoint 3.0 installed

Is there are any conflicts on IIS site

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly, and it is recognized by the installation. So you can just go - I have exactly this thing running...

Thomas